# Binary operator '&&' cannot be applied to two 'Int' operands

Tags: swift, swift2

I wanted to check for below values firstName and lastName. But Swift will not allowing me to access. It is giving error like "Binary operator '&&' cannot be applied to two 'Int' operands".

```
if firstName.length && lastName.length {

}
```

Comment: if (firstName.length >= 0) && (lastName.length >= 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift you cannot check for non-null like in C and Objective-C, you have to write

```
if firstName.length > 0 && lastName.length > 0 { }
```

Comment: Yes I got it fixed (Y).

Answer (score 0):

@Vadian has a good answer, but it could be put more clearly — and there's an extra wrinkle:

For things like logic operators (`&&` and `||`) and the conditions of `if` and `while` statements, C accepts any type -- it just treats any zero value (which includes null pointers, but your string length here is just a zero integer) as false, and anything else as true.

In Swift, though, the only type allowed in such Boolean logic contexts is `Bool` — you can't pass an integer and expect to branch on whether the value is zero, so you have to use a comparison operator like `>` or `==`, or a property or method that returns a `Bool` value.

Since you're dealing with `String`s, you'd do best to use the `isEmpty` property anyway. Getting the length of a Swift `String` is not a "free" computation — the same number of bytes could be different numbers of human-readable characters depending on what those bytes are, so you can't count characters without examining bytes. It's a lot faster to answer whether the string is empty than to check all the bytes.

(Then again, maybe you're not using Swift strings anyway? Those don't have the `length` property you're using.)